Ubuntu 22.04.2 / VirtualBox 7.0.18 captured mouse is not contained when integration mode is off
I have a VirtualBox running windows XP in order to use a couple of old OEM digital camera programmes and some games. VirtualBox is installed via their ppa with extension packs and guest additions installed into XP in safe mode. With the recent update to 7.0.18 I started having mouse problems with the guest in scaled mode and mouse integration off. The cursor initially stops at the edge of the VirtualBox window then travels through the edge and into the Ubuntu desktop. After a bit of waving around on and off the window the cursor can sometimes be mapped to the wrong position in the window or not reach the edges. This continued even when I uninstalled the guest additions, which should not happen. The mouse, once captured should stay fully contained within the VirtualBox. This is my preferred means of executing mouse controlled scrolling in non windowed games.
I have tried re-installing the extension pack and guest additions with no change in behaviour.

Wayland
Ah Wayland, at some point I or a recent upgrade of Ubuntu must have changed to using Wayland. The solution was to log out, select my user then select the little cog bottom right and Ubuntu on Xorg.
Everything seems fine and as a bonus, it now seems that full screen scaled seems to work better than previously with scale factor provided I scale it in the windows desktop before opening the non windowed game.
